# Ajax Control Toolkit HTML Editor not displaying icons

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, htmleditorextender

A couple months ago I began implementing the HTMLEditorExtender from the Ajax Control Toolkit in our application and everything was going fine.  I let it sit for a while and we migrated the application to a new TFS and upgraded to VS 2013 and now that I've gone back to finish those pages I've found the editor is no longer displaying the outline of the textbox or the images on the icons.  You can still type into the text box, but it just looks awful and I can't figure out how to fix it.

Below you can see an example of what I'm talking about.

[image]

I've tried uninstalling AjaxControlToolkit via nuget and reinstalling it, but that has not fixed the issue (although I may be doing something wrong and not removing it completely).

The version of AjaxControlToolkit it says I'm using is: 4.1.7.1213

This is a .NET 4.0 web application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the icons do not get loaded, especially inside an UpdatePanel. I'd prefer a better way to get them to reload, but this workaround works for me. Add this before your UpdatePanel. Note the Visible=False on the Panel that prevents the control from showing.

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlHtmlEditor" runat="server" Visible="false">
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtPreLoad" runat="server" />
    <ajaxToolkit:HtmlEditorExtender ID="heeExtenderPreLoad" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtPreLoad" />
</asp:Panel>
```

Comment: I recently found effectively the same answer but using a div with display:none instead of a Panel.  The div worked and I would imagine the Panel would work as well.  Thank you for the help.